# how to position a child view on right-bottom corner of a React-Native image component?

Tags: image, layout, react-native

I'm developing an app with React-Native.
I want to put an icon on right-bottom corner of an image component, but it always stays on the left-top corner.

Any help? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 31):

```
<Image source={imageSource} style={{position: "absolute", bottom: 0, right: 0}}/>
```

Answer (score 26):

You can use `justifyContent: 'flex-end'` to achieve this:

```js
const withWatermark = (asset, logo) => (
  <Image style={{ width: 200, height: 200, justifyContent: 'flex-end' }} source={asset}>
    <Image style={{ width: 20, height: 20, alignSelf: 'flex-end' }} source={logo} />
  </Image>
);
```

Comment: com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Error: The <Image> component cannot contain children. If you want to render content on top of the image, consider using the <ImageBackground> component or absolute positioning.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this...
Use this : `position: "absolute", bottom: 0, alignSelf: "flex-end"`

```
<ImageBackground
    source={require("../assets/homeAssets/3.jpg")}
       style={{
         height: 140,
         width: 140,
         resizeMode: "contain",
         alignItems: "center"
          }}
         imageStyle={{ borderRadius: 70 }}
        >
         <View
          style={{
          height: 50,
          width: 50,
          borderRadius: 25,
          backgroundColor: "#99AAAB",
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center",
          position: "absolute", //Here is the trick
          bottom: 0,
          alignSelf: "flex-end"
          }}
         >
          <Entypo name="camera" size={25} color="#FFF" />
        </View>
  </ImageBackground>
```